# Eslint fix throw error even on json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, eslint

so I am using eslint to fix my file formats and here are my dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
 "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.10.1",
 "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.10.1",
 "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
 "eslint": "^6.8.0",
 "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
 "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
 "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
 "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
 "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
 "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
 "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
 "husky": "^4.3.0",
 "lint-staged": "^10.4.0",
 "prettier": "^2.1.1"
},
```

and here are my lint staged

```
 "lint-staged": {
   "!(node_modules|build)/**/*.{js,tsx,json,css,scss,html}": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint --fix"
   ]
  }
```

However it throws error on my json file saying that

```
  1:1  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused- 
expressions
```

while my JSON file is this

```
{
  "homeTitle": "Hello <br/> <strong>World</strong>"
}
```

May I know what is wrong with my JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use eslint-plugin-json, if you want to lint json files.